# LightSwitch: An error occurred while checking for updates

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

[image]

I got an error in LightSwitch app: An error occurred while checking for updates. 
That says I should reinstall app what I did but with no effect.

The app runs as desktop client and is published on IIS.

I am not the author of the app and I have no experience with the LightSwitch and Silverlight. I have source codes in Visual Studio 2013.

If you know how to fix it please give me some step-by-step instructions. Thanks.

Comment: Try to turn-off the IIS and then run the App and see what happens

Comment: Thanks for response. Same error.

Comment: This problem I solved. I just republished the app.